# Delay expansion of macro in >{...} column specification

Tags: tables, expansion, columns

Here's what I'm having now

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\test}[1][default]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\test}c}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `\test` expands before table's row has been appended. The desired result would be having

```
\test[one]1\\
\test1\\
\test1\\
\test1
```

for actual columns, but automated with `>{...}` column specification. So that the printed result would be

```
one1
default1
default1
default1
```

I've also tried to apply `\noexpand` here, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it isn't expanded first, but the immediatly following tokens are not what you expect,  not least, `\ignorespaces` is inserted

Comment: Take a look at the `collcell` package to get something that might support your use case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you! I've tried `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mO{default}}{#2\ignorespaces}` and it almost works, but some `Missing {` rises. How can I fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it isn't expanded first, but the immediately following tokens are not what you expect,  not least, `\ignorespaces` is inserted

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

%\newcommand{\test}[1][default]{#1}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{\def\qqq{/#1/#2/}\show\qqq}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\test}c}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

shows:

```
> \qqq=macro:
->/\ignorespaces /[/.
\test #1#2->\def \qqq {/#1/#2/}\show \qqq 
                                          
l.10 [
      one]1\\
? 
> \qqq=macro:
->/\ignorespaces /1/.
\test #1#2->\def \qqq {/#1/#2/}\show \qqq 
                                          
l.11 1
      \\
? 
> \qqq=macro:
->/\ignorespaces /1/.
\test #1#2->\def \qqq {/#1/#2/}\show \qqq 
                                          
l.12 1
      \\
?
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\testb}[1][default]{\ignorespaces#1}
\newcommand\test[1]{\testb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\test}l}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `\def\test\ignorespaces{\testb}` is needed only to swallow the first token after `\test` command and you explicitly set that `\ignorespaces` is expected right after `\test`. I tried out to change it to `\def\test#1{\testb}` and with no surprise it also works. You need two macros `\testb` and `\test` only because `\necommand` doesn't allow to create an optional argument after a mandatory one, but `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` can. I wonder, why doesn't `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m O{default} }{\ignorespaces#2}` work?

Comment: @antshar you need an expandable command to avoid messing up halign processing, you can't use NewExpandableDocumentCommand as it can not do final optional argument. I could use a proper latex #1 for discarding `\ignnorespaces` as you say, that would be better