# Why does this command defined with \NewDocumentCommand behave differently from \def inside tabular column specification?

Tags: macros, xparse, definition

On the first glance

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{#1}
```

and

```
\def\foo#1{#1}
```

should be identical and in most scenarios they actually are, but when the argument is not explicitly follows `\foo`, the command defined via `\NewDocumentCommand` gives `Missing {` error whereas with `\def` it doesn't

This question is kinda a follow up to: [Delay expansion of macro in >{...} column specification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651663/delay-expansion-of-macro-in-column-specification)
, so I will give that example to show the problem. Look at the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\def\test#1{
\newcommand{\temp}[1][default]{##1}
#1\temp
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\test}l}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This one works perfectly fine, but once I define `\test` like so

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}{
\newcommand{\temp}[1][default]{##1}
#1\temp
}
```

Errors rise up.

I figured out myself that if you add `\expandafter` before `\test` in column specification, it works with `\NewDocumentCommand` definition

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\expandafter\test}l}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}
```

But I want to add additional argument, so that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mm}{
\newcommand{\temp}[1][default]{##1}
#2#1\temp
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\test{foo}}l}
[one]1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And here I cannot do the trick with `\expandafter`.

---

So my question is how it make `\NewDocumentCommand` work the same as `\def` without throwing bunch of `\expandafter` or any other bulk solutions.

Comment: beware spaces at ends of lines you are adding lots of spurious spaces. You need NewExpandableDocument command, and more expansion steps, but really you should never need to do this, what is the real use case, there is probably a better way.

Comment: if you really want that, why not `\def\test#1#2{\newcommand{\temp}[1][default]{##1}#2#1\temp}` ? bur as with the first form `\expandafter` applied to arbitrary tokens may not work as you expect

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because I actually also need an optional argument there: `\test{foo}[bar]` that might be omitted: `\test{foo}`

Comment: but you have `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mm}{`  so two m ??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle obviously no, in actual case it's `m O{} m`, but the question is about `\NewDocumentCommand` in the first space so it's not necessarily to mention that.

Comment: if your real case is `NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mo}{ ` that is completely different question as, as explained last time, you can not use NewExpandableDocumentCommand for a final o argument

Comment: @DavidCarlisle optional argument is not final, since `\ignorespaces` have to be swallowed, thus I have `m O{} m` where the last `m` is responsible for that.

Comment: Why are you trying to peek ahead inside a `@{...}` anyway!? Use the `collcell` package to correct the cell content, then you can do whatever with it. (which does peek ahead and some `\ignorespaces` hack; but then it's a "more famous" package so more likely to be correct)

Comment: @user202729 you all seem to focus on the particular question rather the general problem with implicit arguments of a command, defined via `\NewDocumentCommand` — here what this post is about.

Comment: Let's see... I don't think there's any guarantee that `\NewDocumentCommand` must behave like `(\protected)\def`, but I agree that this question **might** reveal a bug on `\NewDocumentCommand`-defined commands being non-align-safe or something. Although the point remains that **you're invoking "undefined behavior"** i.e. tabular environment does not support it by peeking ahead in `tabular` `@{...}`, so it may not actually be a bug.

Comment: Practically speaking, it's easier to focus on the specific problem because, for example, the C++ people usually don't care about why a program that invokes undefined behavior does exactly what it does either. They just say "this is undefined behavior, eliminate it"; until someone find a case where `\NewDocumentCommand` behaves differently from `\protected\def` without invoking "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned before, this is officially "undefined behavior", use `collcell` package then process the data as usual. But this is an answer anyway.

You must understand how `\halign` primitive works and all the 3 kinds of brace hacks do (TeXbook appendix D, or [Understanding Brace Hacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418621/250119) / [Showcase of brace tricks: }, \egroup, \iffalse{\fi}, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9897/250119)) to understand this answer.

---

First, make a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\protected\def\test     {\group_align_safe_begin: \testb}
\protected\def\testb #1 {\group_align_safe_end: #1}
    
\halign{\test\ignorespaces# \cr
123 \cr}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

What's going on here?

the `\test` macro, as defined, will do the following...

- expand `\group_align_safe_begin:`
- grab the `\ignorespaces` token
- expand `\group_align_safe_end:`

Problem arises because, while it does that...

- expand `\group_align_safe_begin:` → increase the master counter by 1
- grab the `\ignorespaces` token → runs into the end of the u part of the template. TeX marks that the target master counter should be 1 at the end of the alignment entry
- expand `\group_align_safe_end:` → return the master counter. Too late.

when the `&` is seen, it will rightfully complain that the current master counter value is 0, while it should be 1 to properly end the alignment entry.

Here the problem is the explicit adjustment of the master counter, which is obviously desired in most common cases.

(side note, in this particular MWE you can avoid touching the `#` part with

```
\halign{\test\ignorespaces\empty# \cr
123 \cr}
```

but this is not applicable if you want to peek into the entry itself)

(by the way, the `\expandafter` you put before `\test` actually have no effect as `\ignorespaces` is not expandable; nevertheless it makes TeX "see" the `\ignorespaces` token and that "touches" the `#` part, thus set the target master counter value to 0 instead of 1)

---

Nevertheless you can choose to "opt out" of it by "undo" the effect (**highly not recommended**):

```
\protected\def\test{\group_align_safe_end: \testa}  % remember to protect this, because the start of an alignment entry is initially expanded to look for e.g. \omit
\NewDocumentCommand\testa{m}{\group_align_safe_begin: #1}
```

It does work in the `\halign` example above.

---

Needless to say you can find an example where disabling alignment-protect is harmful.

For things like `\peek_analysis_map_inline:n` protecting is obviously useful (https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1090),
for things like `clist_map_` etc. it's kind of useful,
for argument grabbing, I'm not sure. (maybe grabbing `&` inside an optional argument counts.)

There's this one (although a little contrived... who needs to take the \cr as input anyway...?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

% the following 4 lines are equivalent to the simple \protected\def  below

%\protected\def\test{\group_align_safe_end: \testa}  % remember to protect this, because the start of an alignment entry is initially expanded to look for e.g. \omit
%\NewDocumentCommand\testa{+m}{\group_align_safe_begin:
%   #1
%}

\protected\def\test #1{#1}

\halign{# \cr
    \test \cr}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```